# git add multiple files from bash array

Tags: git, bash

I want to add filenames/path to a git commit. I have the file path in a array but when i commit I get:

```
fatal: pathspec 'dist/core.js dist/style.css bower.json Source/core.js' did not match any files
```

Earlier in my script I have:

```
DIR=`dirname "$0"`
for file in "${COREFILES[@]}"; do echo $file="$DIR/$file"; done
for file in "${JSONFILES[@]}"; do echo $file="$DIR/$file"; done
TARGET_FILES=$(IFS=$' '; echo "${TARGET_FILES[*]}")
TARGET_FILES=( "${COREFILES[@]}" "${JSONFILES[@]}" )
```

and the error line is:

```
sh -c "cd $DIR && git add '$TARGET_FILES' && git commit -qm 'Current tag $TAG$SUFFIX.'"
```

Other parts of the script that change the source code in files works good. When I do `echo $TARGET_FILES` I get a string, space separated and looks all ok...

Any pointer what I could be missing? or how to do this otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git add '$TARGET_FILES'
```

should be

```
git add "${TARGET_FILES[@]}"
```

And this line does nothing and is probably not helpful:

```
TARGET_FILES=$(IFS=$' '; echo "${TARGET_FILES[*]}")
```

Also I don't think you should use `sh -c`:

```
cd "$DIR" && git add "${TARGET_FILES[@]}" && git commit -qm "Current tag $TAG$SUFFIX."
```

As a whole:

```
DIR=$(dirname "$0")
for file in "${COREFILES[@]}"; do echo "$file=$DIR/$file"; done
for file in "${JSONFILES[@]}"; do echo "$file=$DIR/$file"; done
TARGET_FILES=( "${COREFILES[@]}" "${JSONFILES[@]}" )
cd "$DIR" && git add "${TARGET_FILES[@]}" && git commit -qm "Current tag $TAG$SUFFIX."
```

Comment: Interesting ( and thank you for fast answer!). So `git add "${TARGET_FILES[@]}"` is the right way and also "makes the array into a string" like I had here: `TARGET_FILES=$(IFS=$' '; echo "${TARGET_FILES[*]}")`. Did I understand right?

Comment: @Rikard `git add` adds one file per argument so you have to pass multiple arguments, not a single string. Are you passing the command to `ssh`?

Comment: Ok, so `"${TARGET_FILES[@]}"` is parsed as multiple arguments? so I was doing a single argument with a string.

Comment: Yes it cleanly expands to multiple arguments. Even spaces on elements are preserved.